# Prose markdown turned my slash into &#x2F; and my double quote into &quot;

Tags: prose

I noticed that Prose markdown turned my slash (/) into `&#x2F;` and my double quote (") into `&quot;`

This happened when the markdown is within a code block.  Such as

```
GET https://company.io/api/2.0/resource
```

And in Prose it got turned into

```
GET https:&#x2F;&#x2F;company.io&#x2F;api&#x2F;2.0&#x2F;resource
```

How can I avoid that?  I googled a bit and searched a bit on the documentation of Prose but the answer is not obvious to me.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am providing my own answer here)

Hi I found out the problem was only with the preview within `Prose.io`.  If I use the "more realistic preview" by going to

```
 https://YOUR GITHUB USERNAME.github.io/blog/2018/08/24/THE TITLE OF YOUR BLOG POST.html
```

Then the slashes and double quotes are actually rendered correctly.  Thanks!